# GitLab Get package with generic api get : "package_version is invalid"

Tags: gitlab-api

I'm trying to use :

```
/projects/:id/packages/generic/:package_name/:package_version/:file_name
```

But got an

```
{"error:"package_version is invalid"}
```

This is the route call with token in header (of course)

```
"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/packages/generic/test/api-test/0.0.1/api-test-0.0.1.war"
```

Comment: I have tried with public repo : 
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26309717/packages/generic/com/configureone/aws-code-artifact-maven-extension/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/aws-code-artifact-maven-extension-1.0.3-20210511.220347-1.jar

on this project https://gitlab.com/configureone-public/maven-packages/-/packages/1817322 NOT WORKING

Answer (score 1):

You are providing two packages names - one is **test** and another is **api-test**

Your solution is to provide only one package name named for example **api-test** like this.

```
"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/packages/generic/api-test/0.0.1/api-test-0.0.1.war"
```